# Eclipse no longer automatically adding tags in javadocs

Tags: java, eclipse, tags, javadoc

In eclipse, if I have a method that I want to add a javadoc for, I used to be able to go to the line above the method declaration, type `/**` and `Enter`, and it would automatically create the proper tags, i.e. `@returns`, `@throws IllegalArgumentException`, etc. But it doesn't do that anymore for some reason. I've tried restoring defaults on Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates and Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates and still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative shortcut, which I always use:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>

Just step onto the method and press the key combination.

Comment: That had some strange results:
`@see com.korshyadoo.calendar.DataIO#getField(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`
but has pointed me in the right direction. It appears it's only the methods I'm overriding from an interface that are not automatically tagging.

Comment: That is because you should put the javadoc on the interface, that is the default eclipse behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To check if `Eclipse` is automatically adding tags, open up the `Preferences` screen; then expand to `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Code Templates`.

Expand the `Comments`, and you should see a list of items.
These items are where you can change the auto-generated JavaDoc comments.
For example, the method comment from my settings is as follows.

```
/**
 * ${tags}
 */
```

In any case, the `${tags}` informs the JavaDoc generator to generate the necessary tags for JavaDoc comments on methods. So, if it is missing, just add it. You will need to go and check the other items as well.